# Bootstrap tabbed pane doesn't works

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm making a modal tabbed pane in bootstrap according to [guide](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs). Here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/8208/) and code:

```
$(document).on("click","#tabs a",function(event)
{
    alert("!!!");
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).tab('show');
})
```

This doesn't works (content of tabs isn't shown).  What is my mistake? Do I activate tabs wrong or what?

Comment: Please copy the HTML into your StackOverflow question, don't just link to JS Fiddle.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't include the hash in the href for the tabs, [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/devools/52VtD/8209/).

```
<ul class='nav nav-tabs' role='tablist' id='tabs'>
    <li class='active'><a href='#forPhys' role='tab' data-toggle='tab'>For individuals</a></li>
    <li><a href='#forOrg' role='tab' data-toggle='tab'>For organisations</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Your answer was first.

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to add a # in the href, so that it knows its looking for a ID of an element.

```
<ul class='nav nav-tabs' role='tablist' id='tabs'>
    <li class='active'><a href='#forPhys' role='tab' data-toggle='tab'>For individuals</a></li>
    <li><a href='#forOrg' role='tab' data-toggle='tab'>For organisations</a></li>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/8212/

Answer (score 0):

try this

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <ul class='nav nav-tabs' role='tablist' id='tabs'>
        <li class='active'><a href='#forPhys' role='tab' data-toggle='tab'>For individuals</a></li>
        <li><a href='#forOrg' role='tab' data-toggle='tab'>For organisations</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've forget the "#" on the href. See 

    `<ul class='nav nav-tabs' role='tablist' id='tabs'>
                        <li class='active'>
                            <a href='#forPhys' role='tab' data-toggle="tab">For individuals</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href='#forOrg' role='tab' data-toggle="tab">
                                For organisations</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>`